# SQL Error [1054][42s22]: unknown column 'orderdetails.productCode in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I want to Pick a random customer that has done an order, then display a list of ProductName that he/she buys

```
join orders o on customers.customerNumber = orders.customerNumber 
join orderdetails o2 on orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber 
join products p on orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode 
union select status from orders o  where status = 'shipped'
order by rand() limit 5;
```

but got Error

```
SQL Error [1054][42s22]: unknown column 'orderdetails.productCode in 'on clause'
```

but I make sure the table there is a column **productCode** in **orderdetails.**
can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have given `orderdetails` the alias `o2`, so that is how the table should be referred to.  Similarly for the other tables:

```
customer c join
orders o
on c.customerNumber = c.customerNumber join
orderdetails o2
on o.orderNumber = o2.orderNumber join
products p
on o2.productCode = p.productCode
```

Comment: thanks it works.. but for the last od it was a mistake.. maybe just o2. btw thank u

Comment: @ErmyYuhari . . . True.  I would have called it `od`.